# Extending protorpc StringField

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

I would like to write custom validation for some fields in ProtoRPC messages.
The documentation says, that protorpc.messages.Field class cannot be extended by developers.

Does it mean I should not extend StringField?

E.g. StringField does not ensure that string is non-empty.

I've checked, and my custom string class with my validate_element method works as expected.
Is there any reason, I should not do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `protorpc.messages.MessageField` to create a custom Field. See the [DataTimeField](https://github.com/google/protorpc/blob/master/protorpc/message_types.py#L52) source code for an example of this.